# Sequence returns 49 but should return 36

Tags: c++, visual-c++, math, console

The following code is designed to specifically return the value 36 instead it returns 49 but can't see how or why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MUL(a,b) a*b
#define ADD(a,b) a+b

static int Func1(void)
{
    static int n = 1;

    // Returns 4
    return n*++n;
}

int main()
{
    static int Incs = Func1();

    printf("%d\n", MUL(ADD(1, Incs), MUL(3, 4)));
}
```

Comment: Related (`n*++n;`); http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/3747990

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you check the preprocessed output, because it will not be what you expect it to be.

To be more precise:

- `ADD(1, Incs)` expands to `1+Incs`
- `MUL3, 4)` expands to 3*4
- `MUL(1+Incs, 3*4)` expands to `1+Incs*3*4`

That's why it's recommended to always use parenthesis around the arguments in a macro, like

```
#define MUL(a,b) ((a)*(b))
```

---

Even worse is what is pointed out by Niall in a comment, because the expression `n*++n` leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Undefined behavior makes your whole program ill-formed, and will make any output suspect.

You should really read the accepted answer in the link provided by Niall.

Comment: You should add parenthesis in ADD too: `#define ADD(a,b) ((a)+(b))`. Note that an extra outer set of parenthesis is needed.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I only show the `MUL` macro as a hint to the OP. but you're right about the outer parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it:

```
MUL(ADD(1, Incs), MUL(3, 4))
```

As Incs = 4, it can be written as:

```
MUL(ADD(1, 4), MUL(3, 4))

MUL(1+4, 3*4)

1 + 4 * 3 * 4
```

Now compiler does some [BODMAS](http://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html)

```
1 + (4*3*4)

1 + 48

49
```

Hence proved.

Oh But you don't want this behavior, and want each macro to work seperately
then change your macro definitions a bit

```
#define MUL(a,b) (a)*(b)
#define ADD(a,b) (a)+(b)
```